# Xamarin Improve pinch scale

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, skiasharp

I have a problem. I followed this tutorial about touchmanipulations in skiasharp: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/transforms/touch and it's working great. But for example scaling only works if both my fingers hit the bitmap. The problem is that if the bitmap is very small, I won't be able to scale it. How can I focus on the bitmap with my primary finger and use my secondary finger from anywhere on the canvas to Scale it?

My full code is in that page!

Any idea?

Comment: I went through the code just now. It needs further altering in the onTouch event. Change rect from bitmap size to grid size. Hence will update new answer by 7:00 AM UST

Answer (score 0):

Had refered image apps like Google photos and others. My opinion is there can be two improvements in your image component.

1. Handle touch of the background view instead of the image view.
2. Restrict scaling lower than a minimum scale value. Very low scale values doesn't have a use case as the end user cannot view it.

I'm not sure of your use case implementing the second improvement is entirely up to your decision

Comment: What do you mean by number 1. Can you give an example?

Comment: I meant to add the view with canvas inside another view say a another grid and add touch effect to the parent grid. I'm not near my machine. I'll update ASAP